# How to select last 3 minutes' records from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

this is my SQL table:

```
+----------------+----------------+-----------+------------------------+ 
|   User_Name    |    Password    |    IP     |        Login_Time      |
+----------------+----------------+-----------+------------------------+
|  rthrthrhrt    |   fjdjetje5e   | 127.0.0.1 |   2011-09-24 18:02:06  |
|  Empty         |   Empty        | 127.0.0.1 |   2011-09-24 18:10:01  |
|  Empty         |   Empty        | 127.0.0.1 |   2011-09-24 18:04:00  |
|  rsyrt         |   rwytw4364    | 127.0.0.1 |   2011-09-24 18:08:59  |
|  eryrjrj5      |   Empty        | 127.0.0.1 |   2011-09-24 18:03:56  |
|  reutreuetry   |   reuretyre    | 127.0.0.1 |   2011-09-24 18:06:53  |
|  Empty         |   rthrtrt      | 127.0.0.1 |   2011-09-24 18:05:51  |
|  djdjgdjh      |   66735        | 127.0.0.1 |   2011-09-24 18:09:49  |
|  fgjdgjdhg     |   Empty        | 127.0.0.1 |   2011-09-24 18:07:46  |
|  Empty         |   Empty        | 127.0.0.1 |   2011-09-24 18:11:43  |
+----------------+----------------+-----------+------------------------+
```

I am developing a brute force addon with PHP and MySQL. I would like to select last 3 minutes' records.

for example (what i'd like to do?): time is now: 2011-09-26 9:45:00. i would like to select all records between 2011-09-26 9:45:00 and 2011-09-26 9:42:00.

Comment: What you have tried ? Or you want ready code ?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use this sql query:

```
select * from myTable where Login_time > date_sub(now(), interval 3 minute) ;
```

Comment: select count(1) from myTable where Login_time > date_sub(now(), interval 3 minute) ;  # that will be far more efficient then select *

Comment: @GregoryPatmore , the OP does not just want count, but whole set of records, hence select * or select fieldnames is required

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: how can I achieve this with SQLite?

Answer (score 9):

This query will work even if your table is not updated...

```
select * from myTable where Login_time > select max(time) - interval 3 minute ;
```