# Showing in a table the last different users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a MySQL database like this:

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 | ID |  Time  |    Typeop     |   Operator   |
 ----------------------------------------------
 |  1 |  10:01 |  withdrawal   |     John     |
 |  2 |  10:01 |  deposit      |     Mike     |
 |  3 |  10:01 |  deposit      |     Andrew   |
 |  4 |  10:02 |  check        |     John     |
 |  5 |  10:02 |  withdrawal   |     Simon    |
 |  6 |  10:03 |  withdrawal   |     Dorothy  |
```

The database is populated by each "operator" during his operations and shows an hypotetic bank operations database.

My question is:
How can i organize a mysql query to show the activity of each different operator in the last 3 minutes?
In the case of this example the query must show:

```
 -------------------------
 | Operator |   Typeop   |
 -------------------------
 | Dorothy  | withdrawal |
 |  Simon   | withdrawal |
 |   John   | check      |
 |  Andrew  | deposit    |
 |  Mike    | deposit    |
 -------------------------
```

Notice that John made two operations in the last 3 minutes but it is considered only the last one.
Records in this table are ordered from the last to the older operation within 3-min timeslot.

May I show also a picture at the side of each operator's name? (john.jpg, Simon.jpg...) in the php table generated from the query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553346/how-to-select-last-3-minutes-records-from-mysql-with-php  You can easily use php loops to create HTML img tags and to remove duplicate users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query would do it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT Operator, 
               Typeop 
        FROM   tbl 
        WHERE  `Time` > ( Now() - INTERVAL 3 minute ) 
        ORDER  BY `Time` DESC) AS `a` 
GROUP  BY `Operator`
```

Comment: That will get more than one record for John, since the combination of Operator, Typeop is distinct in each of these rows

Comment: @BenjaminCox No. Group by will keep the first and remove the others. and As its sorted by time already, the last one will be in the final result.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for the code. It works very well, even though (my fault, i didn't explained well in my question!) the resulting table includes also records of previouses days within the ame 3-minutes timeslot. How could I fix the issue? Thanks!

Comment: @mattew add `- Interval 1 day` after `- INTERVAL 3 minute` to calculate last days 3-minute time slot.

Comment: Please elaborate in your question with realistic sample data and sample expected output.

Comment: I added a field "date" in the principal database, this should be helpful. Could we limit the query in the last-day timeslot?

Comment: To use `last day` instead of `last 3 minutes` use `INTERVAL 1 DAY` instead of `INTERVAL 3 Minute`.

Comment: Thanks it is ok now. But how to show results in a php generated table on a webpage?

Comment: This is a very basic question. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
Select Operator,Typeop from YourTableName where Time > date_sub(now(), interval 3 minute)  ORDER BY `Time` desc group by Operator;
```

Comment: That will get more than one record for John, since the combination of Operator, Typeop is distinct in each of these rows

Comment: oo yes.. my bad...edited... :)... used group by now .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but something like this could also work.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Time BETWEEN (CURTIME() AND ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '00:03:00'))
```