# mysql query select entries in the last minute not functioning as intended

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following MYSQL QUERY to select all entries which are 1 minute or less old (yes I know I should be using PDO):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT customname, online FROM users WHERE online > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) ORDER BY online DESC") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Here is my table output:

```
Last Seen

2015-12-14 08:07:36

2015-12-14 08:07:36

2015-12-14 08:07:36

2015-12-14 06:50:30

2015-12-14 06:50:29

2015-12-14 05:41:16

2015-12-14 03:44:00
```

My issue is it's selecting times outside of the parameters I specified. The entries 2015-12-14 06:50:30, 2015-12-14 06:50:29, 2015-12-14 05:41:16, 2015-12-14 03:44:00 far exceed the one minute INTERVAL.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried all the suggestions below and the "duplicates" suggestions and I'm still getting the same results. The datatype for online is datetime.

**If my query is:**

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT online FROM users WHERE online > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) ORDER BY online DESC") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

**then my output is:**

```
Last Seen
2015-12-14 22:51:50 (should display)
2015-12-14 22:51:49 (should display)
2015-12-14 22:51:47 (should display)
2015-12-14 22:16:52 (shouldnt display way over a minute ago)
2015-12-14 22:14:24 (shouldnt display way over a minute ago)
2015-12-14 21:40:15 (shouldnt display way over a minute ago)
2015-12-14 21:34:34 (shouldnt display way over a minute ago)
2015-12-14 21:13:21 (shouldnt display way over a minute ago)
2015-12-14 21:07:57 (shouldnt display way over a minute ago)
2015-12-14 20:12:59 (shouldnt display way over a minute ago)
2015-12-14 19:13:53 (shouldnt display way over a minute ago)
2015-12-14 18:55:40 (shouldnt display way over a minute ago)
```

Comment: "yes I know I should be using PDO", you could at least use the non-deprecated `mysqli` if you don't use PDO :p

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633653/mysql-date-subnow-interval-1-day-24-hours-or-weekday you may have to use `DATE(online)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select last 3 minutes' records from MySQL with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553346/how-to-select-last-3-minutes-records-from-mysql-with-php)

Comment: What data type is `online` in the database? What result do you see if you add the result of `now()` to your query, e.g. `SELECT customname, now(), online FROM users WHERE online > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) ORDER BY online DESC`?

Comment: How do we know when NOW() is? I mean, really.

Comment: the format of online is DATETIME. If i use SELECT customname, now(), online FROM users WHERE online > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) ORDER BY online DESC then I see timestamps which are far older than 1 minute ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function in your query to get the required rows that are entered in table one minute below. Hope this is useful:

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TimeDiff(now(),receivedDate)) < 60
```

Comment: It returned all these values 2015-12-14 22:42:41
2015-12-14 22:42:40
2015-12-14 22:42:38
2015-12-14 22:16:52
2015-12-14 22:14:24
2015-12-14 21:40:15
2015-12-14 21:34:34
2015-12-14 21:13:21
2015-12-14 21:07:57
2015-12-14 20:12:59
2015-12-14 19:13:53
2015-12-14 18:55:40 which still seems wrong

Comment: The issue was PHP and MYSQL were using two different timezones.